# What to enable on router to allow ssh on local network?

Tags: ssh, dd-wrt

I can't ssh into my linux pc (192.168.1.101) from windows (192.168.1.110) after flashing DD-WRT on my router.

When I try to ping linux IP, I get "Reply from 192.168.1.110: Destination host unreachable".

Comment: What subnet mask are you using for the Linux and Windows systems?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you're not blocking ports 0 (ping) and 22 (SSH) on your windows firewall. Your router shouldn't effect your local connection between your machines on the same network.

Comment: Ping uses [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) rather than connections to a port as with SSH, which uses [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) for connections on port 22. A rule to allow pings should permit inbound ICMP. If one only wished to allow pings and not other types of ICMP traffic, then one can allow only incoming [echo requests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)#Echo_request), i.e., ICMP traffic with type 8 and code 0, and outgoing echo replies (type 0 code 0), but that isn't the same as port 0.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that network cables are connected and plugged properly into the router. Sign onto linux box and attempt ping to windows machine. If that doesn't work then ping an outside address like google. Do an "nslookup www.google.com" and pick an IP address to ping. If you are unable to ping the outside, then you have greater problems. It could be your router. Check to ensure you can ping router. Using your web browser bring up the router config page and in the admin tab there is a spot where you can issue a command. Again do the ping to google's ip address. If that works then it's not the router. You can also attempt a ping from there to your linux machine and windows machine. If you can't ping google from router check to ensure you have an IP address in your WAN tab. If not do a release/renew.

I use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) to ssh from windows to linux and works great.